# Add event listener to dynamically created KonvaJS image shape

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, konvajs

I am adding a konvajs image object on each double click on stage as shown below. How can I add an event listener to konvajs image objects created this way, is there a equivalent of the standard javascript addEventListener in konvajs?

```js
stage.on('dblclick', function(e) {


  //getString tell what shape to draw.
  if (getString == "real-input") {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {

      var yoda = new Konva.Image({
        x: Number(stage.getPointerPosition().x),
        y: Number(stage.getPointerPosition().y),
        image: imageObj,
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height,
        name: "image",
        draggable: true
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(yoda).draw();

      // add the layer to the stage

    };
    imageObj.src = document.getElementById("customImage").src;

  }

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, exactly as you did with `stage` node:

```
var yoda = new Konva.Image({
        x: Number(stage.getPointerPosition().x),
        y: Number(stage.getPointerPosition().y),
        image: imageObj,
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height,
        name: "image",
        draggable: true
});

yoda.on('click', () => {
   console.log('clicked');
})
```